# Bing Map API - Calculate distance using two address

Tags: javascript, php, html, bing-api

Is there any way to calculate distance/miles between two address field and display it in HTML

I want to display the distance in `<samp id="searchResult"></samp>`
And I want to display the miles*15 in `<samp id="Price"></samp>`

Please help me to solve it if anyone knows a way to do it.

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="searchBox">Address</label>
    <div id="searchBoxContainer"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchBox" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchBoxAlt">Alternative Address</label>
        <div id="searchBoxContainerAlt"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchBoxAlt" /></div>
      </div>
  <samp id="searchResult"></samp>
  <samp id="Price"></samp>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>

<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=AjwUEXFZA8SMyy8CaJj59vJKVDoWohNXVFz_uGyHlT8N40Jgr-zrhvcxbTNRyDqn&callback=bingMapsReady"
  async
  defer
></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
function bingMapsReady() {
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest", {
    callback: onLoad,
    errorCallback: logError,
    credentials: 'Ap12Gwv9esg5iXgfAh5Ehlbf36MZ-O8051Sl66Zm6glGwq7PSaaKgGPpcOUEGICy'
    
  });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = { countryCode: 'MV',maxResults: 8 };
    initAutosuggestControl(options, "searchBox", "searchBoxContainer");
    initAutosuggestControl(options, "searchBoxAlt", "searchBoxContainerAlt");
  }
}

function initAutosuggestControl(
  options,
  suggestionBoxId,
  suggestionContainerId
) {
  var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
  manager.attachAutosuggest(
    "#" + suggestionBoxId,
    "#" + suggestionContainerId,
    selectedSuggestion
  );

  function selectedSuggestion(suggestionResult) {
    document.getElementById(suggestionBoxId).innerHTML =
      suggestionResult.formattedSuggestion;
  }
}


function logError(message) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

[image]